# ng-hide not working properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation

I am trying to code a solution using ng-hide and and ng-show in angularjs. On clicking on the ng-hide, it delays before hiding to show the view panel. Please what could be wrong. Here is a plunker I have made.

http://plnkr.co/edit/IiSwQ1cijiypdwIXV6K7?p=preview

This is the code view:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <a href="" ng-click="showme=true">Show</a>
  <button ng-click="showme=false">Hide</button> 

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
    <h2 ng-show="showme">This is mah content, yo!</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have added animation effect on that, which has 2s `transition` delayed while hiding `h2` tag. Reducing that transition will improve its speed.
For getting rid of delay while hiding element you should remove `transition` property of `css`
**CSS**

```
h2 {
  color: #2980b9;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  /*width: 100px;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 15;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /*transition: all 0.1s ease-out;*/ //<-- reduced it to 0.1 sec will
}
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IiSwQ1cijiypdwIXV6K7?p=preview)

Comment: On clicking on hide, it delays a moment. I want to avoid this behavior

Comment: @JnG i didn't get you?

Comment: I want to avoid the delay on clicking on hide button. Greetings.

Comment: @JnG remove trasition completely from it,,  here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/byycpBi7Cat0KPHATX5D?p=preview

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks.

Comment: @JnG Glad to help you..Thank you so much.. :)